# Creating Windows store app package from command prompt

Tags: msbuild, windows-store-apps, devenv

How do i create a windows store app package using command prompt?
I have tried devenv, but it just builds the project, it doesn't creates any app packages.
I tried using msbuild, but i have dependencies from other projects which msbuild doesn't recognizes and hence not building.
I tried using MakeAppx.exe, but it is too cumbersome. Can anyone suggest a solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use msbuild with your solution file.

This is how we do it:

msbuild yoursolution.sln /t:Rebuild /p:Configuration=Release;OutDir=..\Release\;Platform="x86"

Your command line parameters will probably have to be tweaked and you will need to do this three times, once for each platform (ARM, x86, x64).